# Attaching underscore or lodash to angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

Is it ok to attach underscore.js variable to angular variable? so I can call underscore like: `angular._` ? Since underscore is less likely to be mocked at testing and we can't declare global variables?

if so, which part of my angular.js application should I add it?

Comment: just `angular._ = _;`

Comment: Yes it's easy to set it, but my question is: is it ok? :)

Comment: Isn't `angular` a global variable?  Can't you treat `_` the same?

Comment: Yes, it's ok. Does it make sense? - not sure. Just use `_` as is or wrap it in the service like `utils` which basically exposes `window._`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to create a wrapper service for underscore that you can just inject where needed?

Comment: ES6 to the victory `include _ from 'underscore';` in test configuration.

Comment: Be careful if you have included lodash.js in your app. You could have some conficts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it would be better not attaching underscore to angular but use it directly.

Answer (score 11):

I prefer to create a wrapper service in it's own injectable module like such:

```js
angular.module('underscore.service', [])
.factory('_', function () {
  return window._; // assumes underscore has already been loaded on the page
});
```

As noted, you should include underscore.js before angular in your html as you typically would.

This approach allows makes underscore accessible in a testing environment.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have seen to do this is dependency injecting it.

check out this link to ng-underscore [link](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-underscore)

or

this link angular-underscore [link](https://github.com/floydsoft/angular-underscore)

Answer (score 0):

If you use ES6 modules you can just import it, if you use the iife approach you can register it as a constant and later inject it

```
angular.module("app").constant("_", _);
```

Still I would recommend an es6 architecture. You can take a look at [this](https://github.com/brechtbilliet/angular-typescript-webpack)

Answer (score 0):

What testing suite are u going to be using?

If u are using karma, u can add any third party lib in the karma config under the files option.  These files will be available in the browser and accessible to your tests. No need to wrap the lib in an angular service or attach it to angular.

Answer (score 0):

If you whant to use underscore you can just simply add it to your scope

Do the following in you controller

```
$scope._ = _;
```

now you use all underscore features inside you html template like

```
<div ng-repeat="value in _.filter(list, ...)"></div>
```